# How to setup laravel 7 on shared hosting?

Tags: laravel, web-deployment

I recently transposed an existing web site from symfony to laravel for which I am a newbie.

At the moment my site is running with Laravel locally using the embedded server.

I created a repo on github and pushed my site on it.

Then I connected to my site via ssh and cloned the github repo on the remote server (shared hosting).
I created a .env file from the .env-example remotly.

I created a subdomain that points to the public folder of the cloned site.

I modified a line in public/index.php to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I launched a composer update command and then run

php artisan key:generate it returned success but I couldn't find any key in the .env file thus I used the same key I use locally.

When I visit the subdomain I get a page like this one:

> Index of /    Name    Last modified   Size    Description     cgi-bin/
> 2020-09-13 15:23    -

I very probably missed something

Comment: "I launched a composer update command" - why did you do that? Updating packages should never be done on any other system than your local one. Also, what **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: If you solely see a directory index, you should check where your webserver's document root points to - especially if that index does not contain any file of your application